# WTSConnectSession

Tags: c++, winapi, wtsapi32

I am trying to use this function to connect to a specific user session. I have tried everything and the function always fails with either `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` 5 (0x5) Access is denied or `ERROR_CTX_WINSTATION_ACCESS_DENIED` 7045 (0x1B85) The requested session access is denied. Even hard-coding the session ID in and the password like this

```
WTSConnectSession(2, 1 ,TEXT("test1"),false);
```

Is there a better way to start a user session than to use this function. I am trying to implement Fast User Switching and this is the last piece in the puzzle is to logon a user session. Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to do something similar and struggling to find good information.

Answer (score 1):

Are sure that you are connecting with username (specified by `TargetLogonId` parameter) in "Remote Desktop Users" group?

You can check it using

```
net localgroup "Remote Desktop users"
```

Another option is to enable security auditing and analyzing security event log.
It will tells you exact root cause of `ERROR_CTX_WINSTATION_ACCESS_DENIED`

Comment: I added all the users to "Remote Desktop Users" group, and still nothing. Maybe a little clarification as to what I am exactly trying to accomplish. So I am trying to implement a custom credential provider, so when a user leaves the area I disconnect the session they are logged into and when that user approaches I want to open or just connect to the that users specific session. I thought that `WTSConnectSession()` would work but now I am second guessing it. Has anybody had to do anything similar?